# Loguru for multiple python file

Tags: python, logging, loguru

I'm new with loguru, so now have problem with logging multiple file. I have used the original python logging, and only need define the logger one time only, then it can catch the logging on multiple file, but the loguru does not. Specifically my project has a tree as

```
myProject/
|- pythonFile_1.py
|- src/
|--- function_1.py
|--- function_2.py
|--- ...
```

As before when using the python logging, the log is defined in `pythonFile_1.py`

```
import logging
import logging.config
from src.function_1 import *

def defineLogger(savingPath, fileName, fileTime):
    logger = logging.getlogger()

    ... (add some handle)
    return

defineLogger(...)


logging.info("SOME CONTENT OF MY LOG")
result = function_1_1(...)
....
```

and in other file `function_n.py` in folder `src/` , I only need `import logging`

```
import logging

def function_1_1():
    ...
    logging.info("SOME OTHER LOG CONTENT")
    ...
    return
```

Then, it will handles automatically catch the log into stdout as well as log file

But when I change into loguru, I define the same logging using loguru with same folder constructions, but it only prints the log that call in `pythonFile_1.py` but not in any `function_n.py`

Known that the `defineLogger` now is `defineLoguru` function is follow tutorial of docs, such as the code below:

```
from loguru import logger

def defineLoguru(savingPath, fileName, fileTime):
    logger.add(<add some needed handle>)

    return logger

logging = defineLoguru()

logging.info("LOG CONTENT")
```